# Linq putting multiple results in one place

Tags: mysql, linq

I have a linq query that returns back multiple runways from an airport but the problem is when I look up a big airport with multiple runways I get the same data over and over again. Is there anyway I can put all the lowEnd and highEnd data into just one result So I can only get back one airport with all the runways included? Database is MySql

Linq query

```
[HttpGet("search/{city}")]
public IActionResult Search(string city) 
{

    var res = (from airportTable in _dbContext.Airports
               join runwayTable in _dbContext.Runways on airportTable.Ident equals runwayTable.AirportIdent
               where airportTable.Municipality == city && airportTable.Type != "heliport" && airportTable.Type != "closed"

    select new
    {
        airportName= airportTable.Name,
        airportType = airportTable.Type,
        city = airportTable.Municipality,
        lowEnd = runwayTable.LeIdent,
        highEnd = runwayTable.HeIdent
    }).ToList();
    
    return Ok(res);
}
```

Result

```
{ airportName = Lansing Municipal Airport, airportType = small_airport, city = Chicago, lowEnd = 09, highEnd = 27 }

{ airportName = Lansing Municipal Airport, airportType = small_airport, city = Chicago, lowEnd = 18, highEnd = 36 }
```

I wanted the data to come back like this, I Figured I can use SelectMany to do this but I can't figure out where I have to put it

```
{ airportName = Lansing Municipal Airport, airportType = small_airport, city = Chicago, lowEnd = 09,18, highEnd = 27, 36}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linq has a database as a source.  I don't know exactly what kind of database it is, but I imagine that the LINQ library for it does not have a group-then-concatenate translation.  So you'll likely have to process your `res` output as is, and then work with it from there, such as below where I group by the airport-level properties and then concatenate the runway-level properties:

```
var finalResult = 
    from r in res
    group r by new { r.airportName, r.airportType, r.city } into g
    select new { 
        g.Key.airportName,
        g.Key.airportType,
        g.Key.city,
        lowEnd = g.Select(r => r.lowEnd).Aggregate((x,y) => x + "," + y), 
        highEnd = g.Select(r => r.highEnd).Aggregate((x,y) => x + "," + y) 
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help this Gives me back exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use a navigation property.  If you don't already have one set up, then start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Once that is done, then it is quite simple, assuming airport has a Runways navigation property:

```
[HttpGet("search/{city}")]
public IActionResult Search(string city) 
{
  return Ok(_dbContext.Airports
              .Include(a=>a.Runways)
              .Where(airportTable.Municipality == city)
              .Where(airportTable.Type != "heliport")
              .Where(airportTable.Type != "closed")
              .ToList()
              .Select(a=>new {
                airportName= a.Name,
                airportType = a.Type,
                city = a.Municipality,
                lowEnd = String.Join(",",a.Runways.Select(r=>r.leIdent)),
                highEnd = String.Join(",",a.Runways.Select(r=>r.heIdent))
              })
              .ToList()
  );
}
```

Of course, you could always also return back an array of runways as well:

```
public IActionResult Search(string city) 
{
  return Ok(_dbContext.Airports
              .Include(a=>a.Runways)
              .Where(airportTable.Municipality == city)
              .Where(airportTable.Type != "heliport")
              .Where(airportTable.Type != "closed")
              .Select(a=>new {
                airportName= a.Name,
                airportType = a.Type,
                city = a.Municipality,
                runways = a.Runways.Select(r=> new {
                  leIdent = r.leIdent,
                  heIdent = r.heIdent
                })
              })
              .ToList()
  );
}
```

and that would look like this, which allows for a more logical relationship, and easier to extend in the future, say if you also need the runway names:

```
{ 
  airportName = "Lansing Municipal Airport", 
  airportType = "small_airport", 
  city = "Chicago",
  runways = [
    {leIdent = 9, heIdent = 27},
    {leIdent = 18, heIdent = 36}
  ]
}
```